# Lotus Notes Domino ODBC Connections on Windows Server

Tags: odbc, db2, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am a Domino/Notes programmer just started to write LS scripts to other external DataBases.

Question
1. I've got one ODBC connection on the Domino server to a DB2 AS400 server.
2. I require access to 4 DB2 databases.
3. Is it enough with one ODBC connection for 4 databases?

The server admin say there is no need for more ODBC connections.

My ODBC experience have tought me I require one unique connection for each database I need to access.

Am I right?

Thanks in advance

Hal, Norway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One ODBC connection to the DB2 server will be enough.  You might specify a default database but you can operate on many databases via that one server connection.

The reverse isnt true, and I am guessing that is where the confusion lies.  When you create an ODBC connection to a Lotus Notes database,you have to create a new ODBC connection for each Lotus Notes database you are accessing.

Comment: Awesome answer thanks. One follow up question. 
How do I access other DB's by using *LSXODBC
I am using fields.SetValue but there is no DB defined. Is it only by making a select statement and then I manage to insert values to the right DB?